Ubuntu acts slow when wifi USB adapter is plugged in
I had purchased a desktop without in-built wifi. After installing the Ubuntu 22.04 using USB shared connection from my mobile phone, I purchased a wifi adaptor from Amazon and started using it. I did notice some issues and upgraded to 24.04 expecting to resolve all.
But, turning off and on was hanging most of the time. I tried reinstalling the system with 24.04 bootable USB and then noticed all issues are happening only when the USB wifi adaptor is plugged in. I can use wifi without any issues when it is connected to the USB only after the system shows the login screen. Is there any way to confirm those issues are with wrong wifi driver and resolve it?
link to dmseg content




Are you able to export those outputs to text (it’s hard to work from screenshots of text). Thanks.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G5h66kD5H7/

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/m4tqJ53b29/

@Will I have extracted text from those images. Otherwise, I don't know how to find the text which is being shown while booting and shut down. I took those 2 images using mobile.

https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu-20210916/issues/92
